# Is there a slight inaccuracy with the current Apple doc on Advanced Memory Management?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Apple's [Advanced Memory Management doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) is pretty well written and precise, but I wonder for its  diagram it has:

(mine is the current revision 2011-09-28)

[image]

In the diagram, after the `alloc` and `init`, the reference count (or the retain count) is 1, which is the basic memory management rule.  After the `retain`, the reference count is now 2.  And then Class C sends a `copy` message to the object, and after that, the object still has a reference count of 2.  The new object has a reference count of 1.

So far this conforms to the rules, but next, on the top of the diagram, Class A sends a `release` message to the object, and the reference count should be a 1?  The diagram has a 2 instead.  Then Class B also sends a `release` message to the object, and the reference count now should be 0.  The diagram shows a 1 instead.  Is this correct, or maybe there is a different way to read the diagram, or maybe some concept is not correct above?

Comment: You can [file a doc bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) if you're so inclined.

Comment: Or just give feedback at the bottom of the page with that diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the diagram is a little misleading in two ways.  One is that for the alloc and retain steps, the associated counts are what happens as a result of the operation.  At the release steps, however, the counts appear to be the state before the operation.  That's all that makes sense to me because there **is** no "Destroyed" method to cause a 1-to-0 transition.

The other misleading part is, I don't think the retain count ever truly goes to zero and I've seen people get confused by believing that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read as : It has a retain count of 2 before the release message, then 1.

It would have been preferable for better understanding to put retain count on the right of the object circle in the retain / alloc messages.